# How to change a GLSL shader parameter in Processing

Tags: opengl, processing, shader, glsl

I'm playing with shaders in openGL using Processing. I'm pretty noob at this and a bit lost.

I found [this thread](http://processing.org/discourse/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1159494801) that has an example on how to use GLSL shaders in Processing.

I'm just trying to the change LightPosition parameter in the shader I'm using. I don't know how to access it though.

Here's my code so far:

```
import processing.opengl.*;
import javax.media.opengl.*;
import javax.media.opengl.glu.*;
import com.sun.opengl.util.*; 

PGraphicsOpenGL pgl;
GL gl;
GLSL glsl;
GLU glu;
GLUT glut;
boolean glInit;
int glutSolidIndex = 7;

void setup()
{
  size(600, 500, OPENGL);

  glu = new GLU();
  glut = new GLUT();

  pgl = (PGraphicsOpenGL) g;
  gl = pgl.gl;
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);
  PGraphicsOpenGL pgl = (PGraphicsOpenGL) g;
  GL gl = pgl.beginGL();

  if(!glInit){
    glsl=new GLSL();
    glsl.loadVertexShader("toon.vs");
    glsl.loadFragmentShader("toon.fs");
    glsl.useShaders();

    gl.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL.GL_LESS);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL.GL_SMOOTH);
    glInit = true;
  }

  gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  //TRS
  gl.glTranslatef(width * .5, height * .5,0.0f);
  gl.glRotatef(160,1,0,0);
  gl.glRotatef(frameCount * .5,0,1,0);
  gl.glRotatef(frameCount * .5,0,0,1);
  gl.glScalef(80,80,80);
  // draw 
  glsl.startShader();
    gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
    gl.glFrontFace(gl.GL_CW);
    glutSolid();
    gl.glFrontFace(gl.GL_CCW);
  glsl.endShader();

  pgl.endGL();
}

void glutSolid(){
 switch(glutSolidIndex){
   case 0:
     glut.glutSolidCube(1);
   break;
   case 1:
     glut.glutSolidTetrahedron();
   break;
   case 2:
     glut.glutSolidOctahedron();
   break;
   case 3:
     glut.glutSolidDodecahedron();
   break;
   case 4:
     glut.glutSolidIcosahedron();
   break;
   case 5:
     glut.glutSolidSphere(1,8,6);
   break;
   case 6:
     glut.glutSolidTorus(1,1.5,8,6);
   break;
   case 7:
     glut.glutSolidTeapot(1);
   break;
 }
}
void keyPressed(){
  if((int)key >= 49 && (int)key <= 56) glutSolidIndex = (int)(key) - 49;
}
```

the GLSL class looks like this:

```
import processing.opengl.*;
import javax.media.opengl.*;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import com.sun.opengl.util.BufferUtil;

class GLSL
{
  int programObject;
  GL gl;
  boolean vertexShaderEnabled;
  boolean vertexShaderSupported; 
  int vs;
  int fs;

  GLSL()
  {
    PGraphicsOpenGL pgl = (PGraphicsOpenGL) g;
    gl = pgl.gl;
    //gl=((PGraphicsGL)g).gl;
    String extensions = gl.glGetString(GL.GL_EXTENSIONS);
    vertexShaderSupported = extensions.indexOf("GL_ARB_vertex_shader") != -1;
    vertexShaderEnabled = true;    
    programObject = gl.glCreateProgramObjectARB(); 
    vs=-1;
    fs=-1;
  }

  void loadVertexShader(String file)
  {
    String shaderSource=join(loadStrings(file),"\n");
    vs = gl.glCreateShaderObjectARB(GL.GL_VERTEX_SHADER_ARB);
    gl.glShaderSourceARB(vs, 1, new String[]{shaderSource},(int[]) null, 0);
    gl.glCompileShaderARB(vs);
    checkLogInfo(gl, vs);
    gl.glAttachObjectARB(programObject, vs); 
  }

  void loadFragmentShader(String file)
  {
    String shaderSource=join(loadStrings(file),"\n");
    fs = gl.glCreateShaderObjectARB(GL.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_ARB);
    gl.glShaderSourceARB(fs, 1, new String[]{shaderSource},(int[]) null, 0);
    gl.glCompileShaderARB(fs);
    checkLogInfo(gl, fs);
    gl.glAttachObjectARB(programObject, fs); 
  }

  int getAttribLocation(String name)
  {
    return(gl.glGetAttribLocationARB(programObject,name));
  }

  int getUniformLocation(String name)
  {
    return(gl.glGetUniformLocationARB(programObject,name));
  }

  void useShaders()
  {
    gl.glLinkProgramARB(programObject);
    gl.glValidateProgramARB(programObject);
    checkLogInfo(gl, programObject);
  }

  void startShader()
  {
    gl.glUseProgramObjectARB(programObject); 
  }

  void endShader()
  {
    gl.glUseProgramObjectARB(0); 
  }

  void checkLogInfo(GL gl, int obj)  
  {
    IntBuffer iVal = BufferUtil.newIntBuffer(1);
    gl.glGetObjectParameterivARB(obj, GL.GL_OBJECT_INFO_LOG_LENGTH_ARB, iVal);

    int length = iVal.get();
    if (length <= 1)  
    {
    return;
    }
    ByteBuffer infoLog = BufferUtil.newByteBuffer(length);
    iVal.flip();
    gl.glGetInfoLogARB(obj, length, iVal, infoLog);
    byte[] infoBytes = new byte[length];
    infoLog.get(infoBytes);
    println("GLSL Validation >> " + new String(infoBytes));
  } 
}
```

And I'm using the [toon shader](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/glsl/index.php?toon3) written by Philip Rideout from 3Dlabs.

This is the vertex shader:

```
// Vertex shader for cartoon-style shading
//
// Author: Philip Rideout
//
// Copyright (c) 2005-2006 3Dlabs Inc. Ltd.
//
// See 3Dlabs-License.txt for license information
//

varying vec3 Normal;

void main(void)
{
    Normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);
    #ifdef __GLSL_CG_DATA_TYPES // Fix clipping for Nvidia and ATI
    gl_ClipVertex = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    #endif
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

and here is the fragment shader:

```
/* http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/glsl/index.php?toon2 */

varying vec3 Normal;
vec3 LightPosition = vec3(10.0, 10.0, 20.0);

void main()
{
    vec4 color1 = gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse;
    vec4 color2;

    float intensity = dot(normalize(LightPosition),Normal);

    if (intensity > 0.95)      color2 = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    else if (intensity > 0.75) color2 = vec4(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0);
    else if (intensity > 0.50) color2 = vec4(0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.0);
    else if (intensity > 0.25) color2 = vec4(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1.0);
    else                       color2 = vec4(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0);

    gl_FragColor = color1 * color2;
}
```

Any hints will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that LightPosition isn't declared as a uniform. It should be declared like this:

```
uniform vec3 LightPosition;
```

Add this to the GLSL class:

```
void uniform3f(int location, float v0, float v1, float v2)
{
  gl.glUniform3fARB(location, v0, v1, v2);
}
```

You will now need to actually initialize the LightPosition parameter. After `startShader()`, but before you call `glutSolid()`, do this:

```
glsl.uniform3f(glsl.getUniformLocation("LightPosition"), 10.0, 10.0, 20.0);
```

That should work (it worked for me).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't use Processing but in C you would do something like:

```
GLint lightPos = glGetUniformLocation(shaderHandle, "LightPosition");
glUniform3f(lightPos, 5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f);
```

Comment: makes a lot of sense and it should work, but I have 2 issues:
1. I don't where to import GLint from
2. The GLSL class from the processing forums already has a similar method: getUniformLocation, but it returns an int. I printed the result and is -1 which doesn't look good.

int lightPos = glsl.getUniformLocation("LightPosition");
  println(lightPos);
  println(gl.glGetUniformLocationARB(glsl.programObject,"LightPosition"));

Both print -1 :(

Comment: See the above answer, that's actually written in Processing.